# How to order a specific value to be last and the rest of the records order by id DESC?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

| id | document_number | document_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12335 | INFORMED |
| 2 | 4562 | APPROVED |
| 3 | 467234 | RESULTANT |
| 4 | 784456 | APPROVED |
| 5 | 114667 | APPROVED |

I want to order all the records by id ASC but the one record with document_status `RESULTANT` has to be last so that it looks like this

| id | document_number | document_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12335 | INFORMED |
| 2 | 4562 | APPROVED |
| 4 | 784456 | APPROVED |
| 5 | 114667 | APPROVED |
| 3 | 467234 | RESULTANT |

This is what I tried but it completely ignores my second ORDER condition

```
SELECT 
l.id,
l.document_number,
l.document_status
FROM load_record l
ORDER BY l.id ASC, (l.document_status = 'RESULTANT')
```

It works if I remove the `l.id ASC` but then it will place the `RESULTANT` last but it won't order the rest of the records by id ASC

Comment: Ordering works left to right, so the records will be ordered by the values of the first column then those records with be ordered by the values of the second column and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `ORDER BY` clause, the subsequent ordering fields (in your case, the second with respect to the first) are consulted only when the previous condition is tied, but in your case "*l.id ASC*" is never tied, so "*l.document_status = 'RESULTANT'*" is never checked.

If you invert the fields inside your `ORDER BY` clause, it should work properly, because `l.document_status = 'RESULTANT'` actually generates tied values, untied by `l.id`.

```
ORDER BY l.document_status = 'RESULTANT', l.id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1qaaJpHtYnaRD9bdLATHM/1).

**Note**: You can omit `ASC`, because it's the default ordering value.

Comment: thanx, I forgot that I needed to order the RESULTANT last first and then order the rest of them. It worked now

Comment: How should I make the RESULTANT to be 1st if I were to change the order to DESC?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to reverse the order of ids as well, you apply DESC to the "*l.id*" ordering.

Comment: yeah but RESULTANT won't be the 1st record shown in this case

Comment: [Try it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1qaaJpHtYnaRD9bdLATHM/2).

Comment: oh you apply DESC to both, now I got it, thanks!!